# How to make dynamically add or remove button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I click add button, it is changed remove button. But I can not change remove button to add button again, When I click remove.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".add").click(function(){
            var element = $(this);
            var I = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + I;

            $("#" + I).attr("class", "remove");
            $(".remove").text("Remove");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".remove").click(function(){
            var element = this.id;
            var I = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + I;

            $("#" + I).attr("class", "add");
            $(".add").text("add");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

`<a class="add" id="1" href="#"> Add </a>`

Comment: protip: `this.id` use native DOM scope to save yourself overhead jQuery

Comment: Can you show your HTML too please, it's hard to guess which classes you have on by default.

Comment: <a href="add" id="1" href="#"> Add </a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify DOM elements with jQuery, anything that is loaded within $(document).ready() won't recognize the change. What you can do is wrap each step in a function, call these on document.ready, then call each again at the end of the other function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        addFunction();
        removeFunction();
    });

    function addFunction(){
            $(".add").click(function(){
                var element = $(this);
                var I = element.attr("id");
                var info = 'id=' + I;
                $("#result").text(I);
                $("#" + I).attr("class", "remove");
                $(".remove").text("Remove");
                removeFunction();
                return false;
            });
    }
    function removeFunction(){
        $(".remove").click(function(){
            var element = $(this);
            var I = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + I;
            $("#result").text(I);
            $("#" + I).attr("class", "add");
            $(".add").text("add");
            addFunction();
            return false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No problem! I just noticed your HTML, it appears that you can remove the first call to removeFunction() from document.ready since that class is only added through jQuery later.

Answer (score 0):

You have both functions listed in document.ready, so you can't attach an event handler to the .remove class since it doesn't exist yet. I would suggest using delegated events:

```
$( ".LocationOfYourButtonInTheDom" ).on( "click", "ThingBeingClicked", function() {
   //code here
});
```

Edit:
ThingBeingClicked would be the type of DOM object triggering the event, in your case this would be an "a" tag

You can read more about events and delegation from the [jquery "on" documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).